# DTF to DTD conversion confusion about cover

Tags: world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, conversion, demon-the-descent, demon-the-fallen

After reading through the translation guide time and again I'm still not 100% sure what the intention is. Does torment replace cover now or is it just in addition to it?

If the latter, what comes to mind is: What are the effects of a lower cover? Is that the same as for DTD demons then?

And if not then the question is do the DTF demons gain glitches just as the DTD demons do (as I assume then that a torment roll is done whenever normally a cover roll would be done)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going to go point by point:

1. Torment is specific to Demon the Fallen and has no similarty to Demon the Descent. The closest similarity is Integrity. See the **Torment** section in the Demon Translation Guide p7-8. There's no link between Torment and Cover.
2. **Cover** is specific to Demon the Descent and represents a fake identity used by the demon to move unseen through the system. Due to their understanding of how reality works, demons can create new covers and switch between them as they require / desire. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53138/when-does-a-demon-become-someone-else-in-a-cover?rq=1) has more info about how covers are made. The lower the rating of a cover, the weaker it is.
3. **Glitches** is a concept specific to Demon the Descent and is related to covers. They represent corruption of the cover.

You're mixing concept specific to either system together in a confusing cocktail. It seems that you want to play Demon the Descent with Demon the Fallen flavour. In that sense I would take inspirations from **Purpose-Built** (p15-16) and **House Conditions** (p18-19).

Comment: So not in addition but replaces completely and no glitches just temporary and permanent torment. wasn't 100% if I interpreted it correctly. tnx